# My website is in Laravel, Now I want to integrate in Wordpress

Tags: laravel, wordpress

My website is in Laravel and is now integrated into WordPress. There are around 50,000 pages. So please guide me regarding this. or give me any plugin or other suggestion.

I didn't try anything; I had no idea about this.

Comment: Because your question is about guidance on an epic, It is a good idea to ask this from ChatGpt, But add more detail to your question and make it specific please!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more specific suggestions for integrating your Laravel website into WordPress with a large number of pages:

1. Manual Integration:

   - Create a custom WordPress theme that matches the design and functionality of your Laravel website.
   - Use the WordPress Gutenberg editor to recreate the pages and copy the content from your Laravel website.
   - Implement any necessary custom functionality or features using WordPress hooks and functions.
2. WordPress REST API:

   - Create a custom endpoint in your Laravel website to expose the required data via the REST API.
   - In your WordPress theme, use JavaScript or a plugin like "WP REST API" to fetch and display the data from the Laravel website.
   - Customize the WordPress templates as needed to ensure proper rendering of the data.
3. Custom Plugin Development:

   - Develop a custom WordPress plugin that communicates with your Laravel website's database.
   - Implement hooks and filters in WordPress to handle the integration logic, such as fetching data or synchronizing content.
   - Create custom admin pages or settings to configure the integration parameters.
4. Existing Plugins:

   - Research and test existing plugins like "Laravel Integration" or "Laravel for WordPress" to see if they meet your specific requirements.
   - Check their compatibility with the latest versions of WordPress and Laravel.
   - Read reviews and documentation to ensure they are reliable and well-maintained plugins.

Remember to thoroughly plan and backup your website before making any major changes or integrations. It's also recommended to test any solution in a development environment before implementing it on your live site.